# PHP shell_exec() cannot Run Node

Tags: php, node.js, ubuntu

`shell_exec()` work and return correct result for other commands. For example `shell_exec('ls -a')`

But it doesn't work and doesn't return anything for both `shell_exec('node --version')` or `shell_exec('/usr/bin/node --version')`.

I actually wanted to run a simple node script from PHP, but I can't even run node cli at all.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with Node 4.2.6 (installed from official repo) and XAMPP for Linux 5.6.12.

Any idea please? Do I need to set some permission on something?

Comment: Check if safe mode is off. Also, this might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/node --version` work from a shell prompt? Is it possible you installed from the Ubuntu repo, which instead installs the `nodejs` binary instead of `node`? Did you enable PHP error reporting (to a file) and check that output?

Comment: @mscdex, yes `/usr/bin/node` works fine in terminal. Even though I did install from Ubuntu repo, I also installed node-legacy which make the command `node` works. BTW, `shell_exec('/user/bin/nodejs --version')` doesn't work as well.

Comment: @toster-cx, as far as I know safe mode was completely removed from PHP 5.4 and later. I am using PHP 5.6.12. But I'll double check.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, outdated info. Just tested on a 14.04.4 with apache, seems to work fine, the only difference was the binary is called `nodejs` as mscdex mentioned. No special permissions, no nothing.

Comment: If you use `exec('/usr/bin/node --version',$out,$ret)` what value is `$ret` after executing the function?  Having the return value may help you find the cause of the issue.

Comment: @EPB, the return value is `1` and if I understand correctly, it means error, probably syntax error, right? May be this is the environment issue.

Comment: According to the documentation at https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes it's `UncaughtFatalException` but I would suspect that you are correct in that it's an environment issue as well.  Try using `shell_exec('/usr/bin/node --version 2>&1')` and see if it dumps anything to `stderr`. If it doesn't, perhaps use `print_r($_ENV)` clean up anything sensitive, and edit your question to include the current environment if you still suspect it's an environment issue after looking at it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
<h2>Node Version</h2>
<?php
$output = shell_exec("node -v");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
</body>

</html>
```